# Is there any way to display whether a song is explicit via my iPhone's Music app? (if i bought explicit songs from the itunes store) with Cydia?

Tags: iphone, itunes, ios, jailbreak, cydia

Is there a way to see if any song is explicit/clean if I bought any songs from the iTunes store and synced it in via iTunes via Cydia apps? (iOS 5, iPhone 4, Mac 10.9 Mavericks)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If explicit you should have a little E next to the title

Comment: A bit late, but true. Should give credit I think